# Admin-on-rest (React) - How to handle browser caching of JS files

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have recently put an admin-on-rest app into production and it works great. However, when I update the app, the updated files within my project src directory are cached. For example I made a change to the restClient.js file, but this only gets loaded after users do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in the app.

What is the recommended way to handle this? Can I somehow add a cachebust to the files? Or should I simply set expires in the index.html file head section?

Ps. this questions is maybe more related to React apps in general then admin-on-rest..

Comment: How are you running your project ? It looks like you're not using webpack or haven't configured it correctly

Comment: I have had someone external install it for me on a VPS. I don't think webpack is used. I beleive Nginx and Node JS are used. I will contact the guy who installed it to see if we can use webpack because it looks like that's what I need.

Comment: I may have misread your question: do you have this problem in development mode or with your production files ?

Comment: Hi, it is with the production files. If I inspect the files with webdeveloper tool in Chrome I can see the name has no cachebust or something like that. I just see /static/js/restClient.js and I think it is cached by the browser? 

In development mode everything is working fine (on my Windows machine with Node.js), if I change a file it recompiles, refreshes the browser and I see the changes immediately

Comment: So I did misunderstand your question... This is not a problem about Admin-On-Rest nor React. There's probably something to configure on the server side. Do you know how your files are served ?

Comment: I had someone install it on a server for me. He gave me these instructions to deploy a new version: 
(1) yarn build (2)  pm2 start portal.sh (3) service nginx restart. The portal.sh does #!/bin/bash serve -s build. My package.json contains a build instruction with value: PORT=5001 react-scripts build. It does not say anything to me, but maybe you can make up something from this? :)

Comment: Would you mind pasting the script part of the package.json ?

Comment: Appreciate your help! Here's my package.json:
{
 "name": "portal",
  "version": "1.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-on-rest": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "PORT=5001 react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }